# Formulate contraints that involve pairings of multiple LpVariables

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp

Is it possible to formulate constraints that utilize pairings of LpVariables in `PuLP`?

More specifically, say that I have LpVariables `x1`, `x2`, ... `x100` (all Binary category), each of these representing an object.  All of these objects have a `type` attribute, which is either `1`, `2`, `3`, or `4`, as well as a `group` attribute, which is also `1`, `2`, `3`, or `4`.

How would I create the following constraint (I am not sure how I would do this in `PuLP`):

Two variables in the solution must be in the same `group` (could be any `group`), and one must of type `1`, and one must be of type `2`.

The solution itself is every single variable, 8 of which have a value of `True` (indicating they are part of the solution), and the rest have a value of `False` (indicating that they are not part of the solution), selected by a myriad of other constraints.

So the constraint I want to add in boolean logic for the solution is:

```
(type 1 object in group 1 AND type 2 object in group 1) OR
(type 1 object in group 2 AND type 2 object in group 2) OR
(type 1 object in group 3 AND type 2 object in group 3) OR
(type 1 object in group 4 AND type 2 object in group 4)
```

Furthermore, is there a way to abstract this constraint to `n` groups in pulp?

Comment: Depends on what a solution is. E.g. a selection of exactly 2 vars or the full set of all vars (which satisfy those conditions; no matter ho many x' are nonzero). Details would help.

Comment: @sascha I added a bit, and hope that it provides more clarity

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pulp add constraint that at least one LpAffineExpression is equal to one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53843348/pulp-add-constraint-that-at-least-one-lpaffineexpression-is-equal-to-one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a complete working example that does what you want. It should produce the output below. As you can see 8 of the x's have been selected, and the rule that at least one from type 1 (type 0 in my example) and type 2 (type 1 in my example) is picked is obeyed, as is the requirement that at least one group has two picked variables in it.

The trick to this is as described in the answer given to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53843348/pulp-add-constraint-that-at-least-one-lpaffineexpression-is-equal-to-one)

```
x_picked: [3, 9, 22, 49, 64, 77, 84, 93]
group_picked: [3, 0, 1, 3, 3, 0, 3, 3]
type_picked: [0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 1, 2]
n_in_group_soln: [2. 1. 1. 4.]
two_or_more_in_group_soln: [1. 0. 0. 1.]
```

Self-contained example doing what you want (Python3):

```
from pulp import *
import numpy as np

n = 100
M = 100
n_grps = 4
n_typs = 4

# Binary varaibles; 1 means include in solution, 0 means don't include
x = LpVariable.dicts("x_%s", range(n), cat='Binary')

# Assign types and groups
np.random.seed(0)

# All of these objects have a type attribute, which is either 1, 2, 3, or 4 (use zero-indexes)
type_of_x = np.random.randint(0, n_typs, n)

# as well as a group attribute, which is also 1, 2, 3, or 4. (use zero-indexes)
group_of_x = np.random.randint(0, n_grps, n)

# Also randomly assign a cost to including each solution (obj. to minimise this)
cost_of_x = np.random.random(n)

# Initialise problem and set objective:
prob = pulp.LpProblem('Minimize', pulp.LpMaximize)
prob += lpSum([x[i]*cost_of_x[i] for i in range(n)])

# CONSTRAINTS
# Two variables in the solution must be in the same group (could be any group)
n_in_group = LpVariable.dicts("n_in_group_%s", range(n_grps), cat='Integer')
two_or_more_in_group = LpVariable.dicts("two_or_more_in_group_%s", range(n_grps), cat='Binary')

for i in range(n_grps):
    prob += n_in_group[i] == lpSum([x[j] for j in range(n) if type_of_x[j] == i])
    prob += two_or_more_in_group[i] >= (n_in_group[i] - 1)/M
    prob += two_or_more_in_group[i] <= (1 - (2 - n_in_group[i])/M)

# Need at least one for the two_or_more_in_group vars to be true:
prob += lpSum([two_or_more_in_group[i] for i in range(n_grps)]) >= 1

# and one must of type 1 (note zero index)
prob += lpSum([x[j] for j in range(n) if group_of_x[j] == 0]) >= 1

# and one must be of type 2 (note zerod index)
prob += lpSum([x[j] for j in range(n) if group_of_x[j] == 0]) >= 1

# Finally require that 8 are picked:
prob += lpSum([x[j] for j in range(n)]) == 8

# Solve and display outputs
prob.solve()
x_soln = np.array([x[i].varValue for i in range(n)])
n_in_group_soln = np.array([n_in_group[i].varValue for i in range(n_grps)])
two_or_more_in_group_soln = np.array([two_or_more_in_group[i].varValue for i in range(n_grps)])

x_picked = [i for i in range(n) if x_soln[i] > 0.5]
group_picked = [group_of_x[i] for i in x_picked]
type_picked = [type_of_x[i] for i in x_picked]

print("x_picked: " + str(x_picked))
print("group_picked: " + str(group_picked))
print("type_picked: " + str(type_picked))
print("n_in_group_soln: " + str(n_in_group_soln))
print("two_or_more_in_group_soln: " + str(two_or_more_in_group_soln))
```