# Pulp add constraint that at least one LpAffineExpression is equal to one

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp

Say I have a PuLP model defined as thus:
`model = pulp.LpProblem('',pulp.LpMaximize)`

And I have added an objective function (it does not matter)

Now I have a list of `LpAffineExpression` objects:
`lps = [l1, l2, l3, ...]`

I want to add to the model the constraint that one of these `LpAffineExpression` evaluates to 1.  How would I do so?

Essentially what I'm looking for is the syntactically correct way to do the following:

`model += (l1 == 1 OR l2 == 1 OR l3 == 1 OR ...)`

Note that I do not know how many how many `LpAffineExpression` objects are in the `lps` list, so I cannot hardcode it in.

In other words, I am looking for a way to group a set of `LpAffineExpression` in the model, such that only one has to be fulfilled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "OR" in linear or integer programming. However, you can use binary variables to simulate such an OR construct. (Or SOS1 variables if big-M's are undesirable; I am not sure to what extend Pulp supports SOS1 variables).

The idea is:

```
1 - M * (1-δ(i)) <= L(i) <= 1 + M * (1-δ(i)) 
sum(i, δ(i)) >= 1 
δ(i) ∈ {0,1}
```

- Obviously the `L(i)` are your `l1,l2,l3,...`
- `δ(i)` is a binary variable indicating if `L(i)=1`. We have `δ(i)=1 ⇒ L(i)=1`.
- The constants `M` can be set to lower and upper bounds of `L(i)`.

Comment: Could you expand on what the δ(i) and L(i) represent? Thanks so much!

Comment: Thanks again.  Is there a way in pulp to set up one binary variable implying the other? As in the `δ(i)=1 ⇒ L(i)=1`.

Comment: Yes. 'δ=1 ⇒ γ=1` (both binary variables) is done by imposing the constraint `y ≥ δ`. This is very basic, so you probably should check with your teacher about this.